# How sick does one have to be to qualify for a "Mi Shebberach"?

Tags: blessing, halacha-theory, choleh-sick

Are there guidelines about how sick you have to be to be included in the *mi shebberach* list read during the torah service?  A cold? Bronchitis? The flu?  Pneumonia?  I'm not asking about private prayer but public prayer.

Addendum: There is no halacha for how sick you have to be to rate a mention on the public mi shebberach list.  Each congregation makes its own rules.
This is what I concluded after reading the comments here and at judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16430/170

(Personally, I find it distasteful to tell someone for whom the matter is very meaningful, "Sorry, you are just not sick enough to make the cut.")

Comment: AFAIK, a sickness is when one is tied to the bed. In such a case he's considered "imprisoned" and needs to be freed. 

Of course, it is a matter of personal feeling and severity, theoretically, there's nothing to prohibit to say M"S for anyone who's not feeling well.

Comment: What is ever too trivial to pray for? As for using communal time, why would there be any guidance other than whatever the community allows?

Comment: I think this is a matter of opinion. In my shul, just last week, we debated this as we have a huge list of about 50 people. As we do Mi Sheberach at each Torah reading, it becomes a *torach tzibbur* to read all these names on a weekday. Our rav decided to limit the list to people who are hospitalized or recovering from surgery, etc. It doesn't belong to people who have a permanent long-term illness in his opinion. It certainly does not go for someone who has just a cold or migraine. (If it did, they would be saying the bracha for me each time I ride the subway to work!)

Comment: @DanF indeed I asked once who rated to be included in the addition to *refaeinu* in a personal shmonei esrei, and R Tabady told me that only serious cases (e.g., people in hospitals) qualified. I specifically asked if long-term chronic sick people (but not in life danger) should be there and he advised against praying there for the same people over long periods of time

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi I've edited that information into the question.  For future reference, the best way to respond to comments asking for clarifications is to [edit] the question.  (And then you can flag those comments as no longer needed, as they've done their job.)  Thanks.

Comment: @DoubleAA A lot of them are ignored these days in most places I've been, but there are plenty of specific rules on the books for specific ways to not waste the congregation's time.

Comment: This seems a duplicate of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16430/170

Comment: @msh210 I agree and have put it on hold as such.  Maurice, see the linked question for answers to your question.  If your question is different, you can [edit] to say how and the community will review for possible reopening.  It looks like the answers there are what you're looking for -- check them out.

Comment: @ Monica Cellio  - I added my conclusion in my question -- No room for an "answer".

Comment: I find it rather distasteful to treat the prayer for well being of the sick as actually just a ritual for the psychological well being of the healthy relative. It makes it seem like that's its sole benefit, not the divine consequence of actually healing the ill.